# How to create a UIImage property that can be accessed from any method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'm trying to learn objective-c and app design for `Xcode` through books and example, but can't seem to understand how to create a global property for a `UIImage`, set an image to that property, and then access that `UIImage` in a different method.

In my **FirstViewController.m** file, I added the following lines:

```
@interface FirstViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *workingImage;
@end

@implementation FirstViewController
- (IBAction)myMethod1:(id)sender {
... bunch of code ...
UIImage *workingImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
}

- (IBAction)button press:(id)sender {
    CGContextRef ctx;
    CGImageRef imageRef = [self.workingImage CGImage];
    ...bunch of code...
}
```

So basically I am trying to create an image variable called `workingImage` that I set in my method to be an actual image, and then which gets used by `CGImageRef` after the user pressed the button. However I don't think I have things setup correctly, because `imageRef` never gets set to my image.

Can someone please show me what I'm doing wrong? (And FYI, this is a code snippet from a very simple app in which the user takes a photo and then I edit it's pixels)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you're assigning the image to a local variable:

```
UIImage *workingImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

when what you want is to set the image to the property:

```
self.workingImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. It is so obvious after you explain it, I just couldn't see it myself. I'll accept after the time limit.